# Why say 彼らは私の勉強を手伝ってくれる instead of 彼らは勉強を私に手伝う?

Tags: grammar, particle-って, particle-さえ

Why say

> 彼{かれ}らは私{わたし}の勉強{べんきょう}を手{て}伝{つだ}ってくれる

instead of

> 彼{かれ}らは勉強{べんきょう}を私{わたし}に手{て}伝{つだ}う

to say "they help me study"?

What does くれる do in the first sentence? Doesn't it mean "to give"?

Also, how do you say "They even said they would help me study" in Japanese?

Comment: These sentences are all grammatically incorrect. If you're asking about how to use さえ, you should refer to your textbook first.

Comment: @naruto How do I use さえ to say They even said they would help me study. I typed these quotes on google translate and they translated to They even said they would help me study.

Comment: Machine translation will try its best to produce something plausible even if you give it incorrect input. It cannot be used to check if your Japanese is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Leebo I edited the question can you please recheck it?

Comment: They even said they would help me study. 彼らは勉強を手伝ってくれるとさえ言った。 I think you should ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 彼らは{かれらは}勉強を{べんきょうを}私に{わたしに}手伝う{てつだう}。(incorrect)

Instead:

> 彼らは勉強を{o}私に教える{おしえる}。

> 彼らは私に勉強を教える。

> 彼らは私の勉強を手伝う。

But these often make you sound arrogant because they fail to acknowledge that they are acting for your sake, so instead you say:

> 彼らは私の勉強を手伝ってくれる。
> They (are kind enough to) help me study.

etc.

Another example:

> 勉強を手伝ってくれ。
> Do me a favor and help me study.

See [くれる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%91%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B).

Comment: Can I also say "Karera wa benkyou wo watashi ni oshiete kureru"?

Comment: Yes, of course.